# Generalised Scraping embed YouTube videos with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I just wrote a script that scrape all youtube links in a given page (this one : https://coreyms.com/) and open them in a browser (this has no particular use beside learning how to do it).

```
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession
import re
import webbrowser

url = input("website url to launch all embeded videos")
if url == '':
    url = 'https://coreyms.com/'

sess = HTMLSession()
r = sess.get(url)

whole_file = r.text

pattern = re.compile(r'https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/(.+)[\?"]')
video_ids = pattern.findall(whole_file)
```

The problem is that it only works with that specific website (because I used the HTML source of it in order to know what my script must search). 
I managed to make the script works with this as well 
https://www.udiscovermusic.com/stories/best-heavy-metal-songs/ 
But with another one : 
https://www.musicgrotto.com/best-classic-rock-songs/ 
It does not work again. I think this is not the good approach. \

How can I generalise my script in order to make it work with any website ?
Is there a common tread I could use ?

I don't know much of HTML and web developpement. (that's exactly why I want to do this)

Thanks